# Extracts emails from files's folder to new file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, debian

I got the line to extract emails from a file to annother like this:

```
grep -oE '[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+' infile > outfile.txt
```

With:

```
grep -oE '[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+' * > outfile.txt
```

I can condense the emails from all files in the current folder to the file outfile.txt, but each line as:
file_name:email

I want only the emails without the file_name in front.
What should I change ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-h` option:

```
grep -hoE '[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+' * > outfile.txt
```

As per `man grep`:

```
-h, --no-filename
         Never print filename headers (i.e. filenames) with output lines.
```